# nsis install executing bat but doing nothing

Tags: batch-file, cmd, nsis

I have a batch file that I need to run within my NSIS installer. It just mount a network drive using NET USE Z: \server\folder. The installer seems to work fine, the cmd is launched and the commands even output like everything is fine [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fkDCS.png), but the drive isn't actually mapped

[image with commands output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fkDCS.png)

the nsis section is

```
Section ""      

    ;Install path
    SetOutPath $INSTDIR
    ;the bat file
    File network.bat

    ;execute bat
    Exec '"$INSTDIR\network.bat"'

SectionEnd
```

If I execute the bat manually the drives get mapped perfectly. I also try executing the net command directly by using `nsExec::ExecToLog '"C:\Windows\System32\net.exe" use z: \\server\folder'` or `Exec "$SYSDIR\Net.exe use z: \\server\folder"` or `ExecWait '"cmd.exe" /C net use z: \\server\folder'` but I get the same result.

The bat content is the following:

```
NET USE Z: /d
NET USE Z: \\server\folder
pause
```

What am I doing wrong? What else can I try? Im testing installer on a Win10 Home edition if it helps.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mapped drives are [not shared across UAC boundaries](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cjacks/2007/02/19/mapped-network-drives-with-uac-on-windows-vista/).

Applicable solutions/workarounds:

- You can use the `RequestExecutionLevel User` attribute in your script if you do not require administrator rights to install your application.
- Use UNC paths (`\\server\folder`)
- If you are installing a application, the application can set the mapping when it is started.
- Use the [ShellExecAsUser plug-in](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/ShellExecAsUser_plug-in) to execute the batch file in the context of Explorer.exe

Answer (score 0):

Anders answers works great and clarify me on which was the problem, in my context I couldn't use 1-3 options so I start doing 4 and it lead me to this [use explorer to run as current user](http://mdb-blog.blogspot.com/2013/01/nsis-lunch-program-as-user-from-uac.html) it gaved me a simpler solution.

```
Exec '"$WINDIR\explorer.exe" "$INSTDIR\network.bat"'
```

Just point one more thing, if the installer, is not ELEVATED, this logic is not relevant, because then you can just run `Exec` which will have the same elevation as your process.

Comment: This is a huge hack that I cannot recommend. This is basically a bug in Explorer.exe and could stop working in future versions.